# How to stub https.request response.pipe with sinon.js and promise and possible paths?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, chai, sinon

I am currently doing something similar as described in [How to stub https.request response.pipe with sinon.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42399877/how-to-stub-https-request-response-pipe-with-sinon-js)

Actually I am doing the same but my code is a bit more complex since I have multiple path ways (conditions) regarding the request code handling and use a promise instead of callback. Furthermore, I use the https instead of the request module.

I have currently the following code which I can't get to work:

```
//utils.js
/**
 * Fetches the repository archive
 *
 * @param url The archive download url
 * @param dest The temp directory path
 * @param accessToken The access token for the repository (only available if private repository)
 */
exports.fetchArchive = function(url, dest, accessToken) {
    let options = {
        headers: {}
    }
    if (accessToken) {
        options.headers = {'PRIVATE-TOKEN': accessToken}
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        https
            .get(url, options,(response) => {
                const code = response.statusCode;
                if (code >= 400) {
                    reject({ code, message: response.statusMessage });
                } else if (code >= 300) {
                    this.fetchArchive(response.headers.location, dest).then(resolve, reject);
                } else {
                    response
                        .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(dest))
                        .on('end', () => resolve(null))
                        .on('error', () => reject({ code, message: response.statusMessage }));
                }
            })
    });
}
```

_

```
//utils.test.js
    describe('public fetchArchive', () => {
        it(`should have a redirect status code (>= 300) and redirect and thus be called at twice`, () => {
            let options = {
                headers: {}
            }
            options.headers = {'PRIVATE-TOKEN': repoPropsPrivate.accessToken}

            const mockResponse = `{"data": 123}`;
            // //Using a built-in PassThrough stream to emit needed data.
            const mockStream = new PassThrough();
            mockStream.push(mockResponse);
            mockStream.end(); //Mark that we pushed all the data.

            sinon
                .stub(https, 'get')
                .callsFake(function (privateUrl, options, callback) {
                    callback(mockStream);
                    return Promise.resolve(null); //Stub end method btw
                });


            //Finally keep track of how 'pipe' is going to be called
            sinon.spy(mockStream, 'pipe');

            return utils.fetchArchive(privateArchiveUrl, privateArchiveDest, repoPropsPrivate.accessToken)
                .then((res) => {
                    sinon.assert.calledOnce(mockStream.pipe);
                    //We can get the stream that we piped to.
                    let writable = mockStream.pipe.getCall(0).args[0];
                    assert.equal(writable.path, './output.json');
                })
        });
    });
```

I am not sure how to adapt the code from the other post to fit my requirements.

I don't know how to send a response including the request code followed by the stream, and furthermore how to process the promise then in the test.

I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom writable stream in order to have more control over your mocked data, like adding `statusCode` or `headers` properties on the stream object. I would create something like this (this simulates an actual stream where `_read()` will emit 4 bytes of data from the given `responseBody` until there's nothing left to read:

```
const {Readable} = require('stream');

class ResponseStreamMock extends Readable {
    constructor(statusCode, responseBody) {
        super();
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
        this.headers = {location: 'someLocation'};
        this.responseData = responseBody !== undefined ? Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(responseBody), "utf8") : Buffer.from([]);
        this.bytesRead = 0;
        this.offset = 4;
    }

    _read() {
        if (this.bytesRead >= this.responseData.byteLength) {
            this.push(null);
        } else {
            setTimeout(() => {
                const buff = this.responseData.toString('utf8', this.bytesRead, this.bytesRead + this.offset);
                this.push(Buffer.from(buff));
                this.bytesRead += this.offset;
            }, Math.random() * 200)
        }
    }
}
```

You can then use it like this in your unit-test:

```
describe('public fetchArchive', () => {
    it(`should redirect for status code >= 300, then pipe response into fs-stream`, async function () {
        this.timeout(5000)
        const httpGetStub = sinon.stub(https, 'get');
        let redirectStream = new ResponseStreamMock(300);
        let responseStream = new ResponseStreamMock(200, {"someData": {"test": 123}});
        httpGetStub.onCall(0).callsFake(function (privateUrl, options, callback) {
            redirectStream.resume(); // immediately flush the stream as this one does not get piped
            callback(redirectStream);
        });
        httpGetStub.onCall(1).callsFake(function (privateUrl, options, callback) {
            callback(responseStream);
        });

        sinon.spy(redirectStream, 'pipe');
        sinon.spy(responseStream, 'pipe');
        const fsWriteStreamStub = sinon
            .stub(fs, 'createWriteStream').callsFake(() => process.stdout); // you can replace process.stdout with new PassThrough() if you don't want any output

        const result = await fetchArchive("someURL", "someDestination", "")

        sinon.assert.calledOnce(fsWriteStreamStub);
        sinon.assert.calledOnce(responseStream.pipe);
        sinon.assert.notCalled(redirectStream.pipe);
        assert.equal(result, null);
    });
});
```

Note that you need to change the implementation of `fetchArchive` a bit to get this to work:

```
exports.fetchArchive = function fetchArchive(url, dest, accessToken) {
    let options = {
        headers: {}
    }
    if (accessToken) {
        options.headers = {'PRIVATE-TOKEN': accessToken}
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        https
            .get(url, options, (response) => {
                const code = response.statusCode;
                if (code >= 400) {
                    reject({code, message: response.statusMessage});
                } else if (code >= 300) {
                    fetchArchive(response.headers.location, dest).then(resolve, reject);
                } else {
                    response.on('end', () => resolve(null))
                    response.on('error', () => reject({code, message: response.statusMessage}));
                    response.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(dest))
                }
            })
    });
}
```

Comment: just one more problem, it says `cannot read property 'on' of undefined`, do you have an idea how to handle or mock this?

Comment: I replaced 
`const fsWriteStreamStub = sinon.stub(fs, 'createWriteStream').callsFake(() => process.stdout);` 
with `const fsWriteStreamStub = sinon.stub(fs, "createWriteStream").withArgs(privateArchiveDest).returns(new PassThrough());
`

to solve the error